# Block-wrapping semaphore blocking main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, sdwebimage

I've got an API connector that downloads images asynchronously from an API (basically a smart wrapper around SDWebImageManager). This serves my purpose perfectly, except in one rare instance I need to use the images as in an image slideshow datasource delegate that expects a UIImage to be returned:

```
- (UIImage*)slideShow:(KASlideShow *)slideShow imageForPosition:(KASlideShowPosition)position
{
    return [self randomImageFromConfig];
}
```

So I'm trying to use a semaphore to wrap my block call so that I can ensure the image is returned before the slideshow datasource method completes:

```
- (UIImage*)randomImageFromConfig
{
    __block UIImage* returnImage;
    NSMutableArray* slideShowImages = [[kGlobalRemoteConfig valueForKeyPath:@"images.home"] mutableCopy];
    if (slideShowImages && slideShowImages.count > 0)
    {
        [slideShowImages shuffle];
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [ImageDownloader imageForId:slideShowImages[0] collection:@"images" operation:nil completion:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
            returnImage = image;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
    return returnImage;
}
```

But this appears to be blocking the main thread? Is this somehow related to my underlying method calling SDWebImage? Or am I just being silly? How can I get this block operation to work? Or is there a better way to go about this datasource?

Comment: No, it is caused by you blocking on a semaphore in the main thread.

Comment: If the images aren't available yet then I suggest you use some placeholder image or an activity view or something until the image is available.

Comment: I have that - but I want to start the slide show as soon as one image is done loading; then have it progress as each one is finished.

Comment: Then you should either provide a callback block, a delegate method or post an NSNotification

Comment: Nevermind - that wasn't the point. I can't create a callback block here - it's a third party module. I'll just have to fork and rewrite it to support blocks.